# Suppose $f(x)$ is a nonnegative convex function in $[0,1]$, prove an inequality.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is a nonnegative convex function in $[0,1]$. Prove:

> $$\displaystyle \int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\frac43\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2$$

I have tried `Cauchy Mean Value Theorem`:
Construct $\displaystyle F(x)=\frac{\displaystyle \int_0^1 f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\displaystyle \left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2}$... But it doesn't work :-(
Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Where $f^2(x)\equiv f(f(x))$ or $[f(x)]^2$?

Comment: @KennyLau The second one, most likely.

Comment: @KennyLau $\big(f(x)\big)^2\triangleq f^2(x)$

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you're in a probability space and you have a convex function, so try Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx=\int_0^1x^4\,dx=0.2,
$$
while
$$
\frac43\,\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right)^2=\frac43\,\left(\int_0^1x^2\,dx\right)^2=\frac4{27}=0.\overline{148}.
$$

Comment: All to easy!  +1

Comment: Excuse me, but $f(x)=x^2$ should be concave function in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: For any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, and $t\in[0,1]$, you have $$ (tx+(1-t)y)^2\leq tx^2+(1-t)y^2.$$ That makes it [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).